# Is there any way to automatically restore the “file upload question” folder of a Google Form via App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am currently working on a project to automatize a monthly task in my company which is about the collection and confirmation of certain information of a few hundred people.

The collection of information is done via a monthly created Google Form.

I wrote a working code with Google Apps Script which does, among other things, the automatic “creation” of that monthly Google Form. To be more specific, the code does not actually create the form from scratch but duplicates a master file and edits the required parts.

Everything works besides one part and that is the problem I would like to ask you about:

The said form contains a file upload question for pictures, which is essential for this task.

It appears that it is currently not possible to add file upload questions via Apps Script:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72151985

However that is not directly a problem for me as the script successfully duplicates the master file which does already contain a file upload question.

The issue I have, is that the newly created form has no Google Drive file upload folder created or assigned to it, which is required to receive answer when a file upload question is included.
To solve it, I manually have to open the edit version of the form.
Once opened, I will then get directly a notification displayed (“ Missing File Upload folders”) and after clicking on the “Restore” button of that said notification, the folders are automatically created and assigned in the same folder the form is placed. While this is technically a fix, it will not help me here since the whole process needs to be automated.

I tried to fix the problem by automatically creating the same folder structure via Apps Script as it would be created by Google Forms after clicking on “Restore”. But unfortunately it did not help since the folders are probably assigned via ID.(It just results in the same folders being created twice)

Do you know any way, even if it is some far workaround to solve this?

I thought about some way to just automatically click on the recover button…

Comment: I think that issue is for video not images. I have uploaded images and saved them in my Photos Library via apps script.  Forms do create a folder for uploads look in the folder where the Form was created.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think there is a misunderstanding -maybe on my side. Yes Google Forms does create the related folder  under normal circumstances (when used manually). But there is no folder created when the form was duplicated via Apps Script

Comment: In summary, your main issue is that these files are not handled?

Comment: Thank you for replying and sorry for the huge amount of information. In summary the issue is that when automatically duplicating a Google Form, which contains a file upload question via apps script, the required folder for this question type is not automatically created with it. The only way I found is to “restore “ it manually inside the form. If the folder is not created the form is not accepting replies. Furthermore, manually fixing this problem is not an option for me. It has to be done automated in some kind of way

Comment: As far as I understand the main issue here is that you want to assign a folder for each user. Can you please share the code previously mentioned in your post?